# Can't be redirected after form action in Django

Tags: python, django

I created a form for creating a new item in Django. The app should be redirected to `item_new` but it's not working. This below error occurs.

> Page not found
>   http://127.0.0.1.8000/item/new

**show.html**

```py
    <form
      action="{% url 'item_new' %}"
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="formItem">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="name" name="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="formBtn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btnPrimary" value="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('item/<slug:slug>/', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
    path('item/new/', views.item_new, name='item_new'),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
def item_detail(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'item/show.html', {'item': item})

def item_new(request):
    return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `urls.py` file, change the order of lines. Like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('item/new/', views.item_new, name='item_new'),
    path('item/<slug:slug>/', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
]
```

The order of urls, does matter. In your current situation, requests made to `http://127.0.0.1.8000/item/new` will be sent to `item_detail` view function instead of `item_new`.